# Other type of "const"?

Tags: c++, oop, constants

consider the following code:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    int GetValue() const { return aVeryImportantValue; }
    void SetValue(int value) { aVeryImportantValue = value; }

private:
    int aVeryImportantValue;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Bar &bar) : _bar(bar) {}

    void SetBar(const Bar &bar) { _bar = bar; }//my compiler won't like this
    int GetValue() const { return _bar.GetValue(); }

private:
    const Bar &_bar;
};
```

What if I want to be able to "inspect" different Bar objects through Foo but also ensure that Foo won't actually change the contents of Bar? Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of a const reference, which you try to change (but cannot), can you use a const pointer?  `const Bar* _bar;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pointer to constant object:

```
const Bar *_bar;
```

You can switch a pointed variable and be sured that Foo will not change it's state.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Bar *bar) : _bar(bar) {}
    void SetBar(const Bar *other) { _bar = other; }
    int GetValue() const { return _bar->GetValue(); }

private:
    const Bar *_bar;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Once a reference is initialized, it can't be reseated to refer to a different object. Instead you should use a pointer.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Bar &bar) : _bar(&bar) {}

    void SetBar(const Bar &bar) { _bar = &bar; }
    int GetValue() const { return _bar->GetValue(); }

private:
    const Bar *_bar;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not going to compile because _bar is a reference, which can only be initialized once. Just get rid of the SetBar function because it makes no sense to try to modify a const or reference object.